# What must be the dimensions of the matrices in order to use element-wise division?

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
res = A ./ B
```

I tried,

```
res = [1 2] ./ [1 2]
res = [1 2] ./ [1 2; 2 3] 
res = [1 2] ./ [1 2; 2 3; 3 4]
res = [1 2; 2 3] ./ [1 2; 2 3]
```

All of them works.

But, the following doesn’t work,

```
res = [1 2; 2 3] ./ [1 2; 2 3; 3 4]
```

So, what is the rule for the dimensionality actually?

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html)?

Comment: Do you want matrix division or element-wise division of matrices? If you want (right-)matrix division use `/`, without the dot

Comment: Then your title is misleading. I suggest you replace _right divide matrix operation_ by _element-wise division_ for future reference

Comment: @anonymous I meant replace only the last part. I've changed the title to that; see if you agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is some of the confusion that has cropped up thanks to MATLAB's new [automatic dimension broadcasting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html).

First of all, note that the `./` operator is an *element-wise operation*.

In versions of MATLAB prior to R2016b, use of this operator would require the two inputs to be *exactly* the same dimension.

```
[1 2] ./ rand(4)
```

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

If you wanted to apply this element-wise operation to multiple columns in a matrix (as you've shown with your second example), you had to use `bsxfun`

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, [1 2], [1 2; 2 3]);
```

The rule is that the non-singleton dimensions of the two inputs must match.

> Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

So in the example above, the first array has a first dimension of `1` and second dimension of `2`. The second input has a first dimension of `2` and second dimension of `2` so this criteria is satisfied.

In R2016b, MATLAB introduced automatic broadcasting of dimensions which have the *same effect* as `bsxfun`, it's just now built into the operator. **The same criteria is required to perform the operation**

In your example that failed

```
[1 2; 2 3] ./ [1 2; 2 3; 3 4]
```

The size of the first input is `[2 x 2]` and the size of the second is `[3 x 2]`. In this case, the first input dimension does not match, therefore the operation fails.

Comment: See also: [Compatible Array Sizes for Basic Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html)

Comment: @anonymous To answer that you should read Suevers fantastic answer... here.